# array_unique() not working - mixed with nonArray

Tags: php, arrays

I am having some trouble with removing duplicates from an Array. This is my code:

```
$invoice_numbers = array_unique($invoice_numbers, SORT_REGULAR);
return $response->withJson($invoice_numbers);
```

**$invoice_numbers:**

```
 {
    "0": [
    "8250",
    "8436",
    "8584",
    "8708",
    "8838",
    "9076",
    "9125",
    "9186"
    ],
    "1": [
    "8250",
    "8436",
    "8584",
    "8708",
    "8838",
    "9076",
    "9125",
    "9186",
    "9895"
    ],
    "3": [
    "9758",
    "9799",
    "10168",
    "10227",
    "10465",
    "10517",
    "10655",
    "10729",
    "10758"
    ],
    "4": [
    "9798",
    "10226",
    "10516"
    ],
    "5": [
    "10926",
    "11246",
    "11591",
    "11790",
    "11791",
    "11802",
    "11803"
    ],
    "6": [
    "10897",
    "11002",
    "11142",
    "11277",
    "11279",
    "11345",
    "11458",
    "11478",
    "11492",
    "11498",
    "11501",
    "11526",
    "11676",
    "11761",
    "11780",
    "11781",
    "11833",
    "11946",
    "12031",
    "12048",
    "12119"
    ],
    "7": "12201",
    "8": [
    "11214",
    "11502",
    "11538",
    "11677",
    "11834",
    "12120"
    ],
    "9": "11643"
    }
```

Now i know that this does not work with multidimensional array. But i also tried this: (Note that key nr.9 is not an array then it throws an error)

```
$invoice_numbers = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $invoice_numbers), SORT_REGULAR);
return $response->withJson($invoice_numbers);
```

Can someone help me with creating a unique value in array? Thanks

> This is the error: Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #8 is not an
>   array

And result is "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses `array_reduce()` to iterate over the initial array and merge the individual components.  As you can see though some aren't arrays - so I use `is_array($element)?$element:[$element]` which if is isn't an array, it makes it an array...

```
$invoice_numbers = array_reduce($invoice_numbers, function ($list, $element) {
    return array_merge($list, is_array($element)?$element:[$element]);
}, []);

return $response->withJson(array_unique($invoice_numbers, SORT_REGULAR));
```